# Removing clutter in unclear questions with many clarifying comments

Tags: support, policy

Consider [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1091119/renaming-a-bunch-of-folders-using-a-pattern/) where there now exist 6 user edits and 11 comments before the requirements were clear. Is there a process for rewriting the entire question and removing the comments used to clarify the question?

I tried to look around for the correct process for this, but didn't find any clear guidelines.

Comment: Looks like the author of that question decided to delete their question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users who edit their posts should integrate the new information rather than chopping the post up into sections based on the sequence of edits. We have the revision history if we need to look back and determine what the post was like at a given time.

Once the question is made answerable, the clarifying comments that got it there are no longer needed. Delete your own comments, if you made any that are now unnecessary, and flag one of the rest as obsolete. Alternatively, use a custom comment flag reason asking the moderator to torch all the comments - sometimes they clean all the comments in response to one normal flag, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

The process is to go ahead and do so. There is no need for "Edit" and "Update" headings all over the question. Remove those and rewrite as necessary the rest of the sentences to form a coherent whole.

Comment: Clarification: The comments will need to be cleaned up by a mod, or by the users that wrote them.