# Use of [moderation] in Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

## TL;DR:

Should [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) be added to questions about the general practices of using moderation privileges in Super User? Could it be better to create a new tag, i.e. "community practices" or "best practices" to make it easier to find the most relevant posts about Super User community, rules, policies, and culture?

What are the available features that help to find discussions about the current rules, policies, and workings (aka community standards) for using the moderation privileges of Super User?

---

## Specific real situation

I created multiple filters (filter names in bold),

1. **Google Chrome** for questions having one of the tags that I found related to this web browser
2. **Google Drive** for questions having one of the tags I have found related to the online file storage service for end-users from Google.
3. **Google apps** for questions having one of the tags I have found related to Google software applications for end-users not included in the previous filters.

[Google apps](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets+or+google-search+or+google-chrome-os+or+google-workspace+or+google-calendar+or+google-docs+or+google-maps+or+google-earth+or+google-accounts+or+google-contacts?sort=Newest&uqlId=503) show many closed questions, so I manually added `closed:0` to the search box. The Relevant tab showed me the following question as the second result:

[How do I simplify this if statement to just add 1 every time (and possibly go with no limit)?](https://superuser.com/q/197188/1794161)

The question was posted on October 7, 2010. [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) was already a "full site" (it graduated on September 30, 2010). The question body of this question only includes a spreadsheet formula. It has [google-docs](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-docs), which doesn't make sense nowadays. It includes [microsoft-excel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel), [spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet), and [google-spreadsheet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet). It's unclear if the OP is looking for a formula that works in multiple spreadsheet applications or just added as many tags as possible in 2010 to reach the broadest audience.

There is a meta post from 2016 asking how to handle questions like  this:

[Correct way to handle users requesting scripts/formulae?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11188/1794161)

The above meta post only includes [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). I want meta posts like this to have a tag that helps find related questions more efficiently in this case about the *community standards*.

In the meantime, I created an outline in Diigo to create a personal collection of meta posts like the above. Is this the best I can aspire to (search and collect using external tools)?

As a user with that barely has privileges to participate in Meta (I can flag and comment but not edit meta posts),

- What is the proper way to ask to add tags to the above post?
- Is my only option to request to add an existing tag like [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), or I'm allowed to ask to create a new tag?
- If I'm allowed to request to create a new tag, what should I include in a request to add a new tag?

## Addendum

As long-time users know, Super User is part of The Trilogy of four (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, and the first Meta). This meta site has some relatively recent posts related to interactions with OPs (answering, commenting, flagging, etc.)

There are 14 questions with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). Still, other questions that do not have this tag discussing the use of moderation privileges might have important insights about how these privileges are better used in Super User.

Some posts do not have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq); having [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation), might be worth reading by new users and probably all who use their moderation privileges. Below there are a few examples (newest first):

- [Continuous overuse of moderation rights](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14041/1794161)
- [How to handle users appropriating other users' correct answers](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12903/1794161)
- [Should I handle rude fragments myself? or is it better to get moderator involved?](https://meta.superuser.com/q/12515/1794161)

Other posts do not have [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and not [moderation](/questions/tagged/moderation) but have tags about moderation privileges like [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging), [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [vote-to-close](/questions/tagged/vote-to-close).

Finding the most relevant post about using the moderation privileges looks to be hard as but these tags also are used in posts about specific questions, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), and [support](/questions/tagged/support). Below there are a few examples:

##### No tags

- [Don't post "never happened to me" answers](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14994/1794161)

##### [flagging](/questions/tagged/flagging), [close-votes](/questions/tagged/close-votes), [close-reasons](/questions/tagged/close-reasons), [policy](/questions/tagged/policy)

- [What details do you need? Or please stop voting to close as “Needs details or clarity”!](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14905/1794161)
- [We have bad question closing habits](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14725/1794161)
- [Removing clutter in unclear questions with many clarifying comments](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11598/1794161)

I think that tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), should be reserved for community rules and policies that have an authoritative status and are about the community standards, not for discussions about best practices or about the community aspirations (stuff that goes beyond the minimum that is expected from people that use the moderation privileges).

---

#### Community Building

[Community Building Stack Exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/) has `rules-and-polices`, `community-standards`, among other tags.

##### [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/rules-and-policies/info)

> For questions about creating, changing, clarifying rules or policies for a community or group of communities.

##### [community-standards](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/community-standards/info)

> The rules that a community must follow.

---

The idea is to make it easier to find discussions about the workings of Super User that might not be the same as other sites, and that might have evolved over time.

## Related

### Community Building

- [How to handle user whose heavy participation causes minority of bad contributions to be a drain on moderator resources?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/694/7020)
- [How much effort should be put forth in directing new users who post without familiarity?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/700/7020)

### Meta Stack Exchange

Newest first.

- [Can you do a better job of informing new meta users of the MSE M-child difference?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291687/1359324)
- [Are there best practices for individual sites to use their per-site-meta [faq] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290991/1359324) (no answers)
- [How do per-site Metas differ from Meta Stack Exchange, and where should I go to ask my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229789/1359324)
- [How is consensus determined on Meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177550/1359324)

### Stack Overflow Meta

[Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316468/21769175) to [When and how do mature [faq-proposed] posts graduate to [faq]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316464/21769175)

Comment: Is this asking something or suggesting something or what? I feel like this is a wall of text and information from across the network with little in the way of actual direction or purpose beyond "other sites do <something>" and no real "we might want to do this as well" or even indication of why them doing that might benefit us.

Comment: Are you suggesting we remove the vague `moderation` tag? Your question title does not seem to have any real relevance to the question body. What do you want done with the tag? What should we do instead? Why would that be better? As mentioned I don't really see any solid purpose to this post apart from collecting links from random places and suggesting that there is some unknown connection between them.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks for reading and for your feedback. Moved and reworded a couple of statements to the top as TL;DR:

Comment: @Mokubai I edited the question. As mentioned in a previous comment, I added a TL;DR. I just added an actual sample situation that I'm facing right now.

Comment: Just "moderation" feels a bit like a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that rather than being added to questions should really be removed. Without some description or other clarifying tags there is no clue what kind of "moderation" you are talking about. Moderation as a job includes lots of things from retagging, undeletion of questions all the way up to site policy changes. I agree with Sathyajith that meta is almost entirely about site moderation and so the tag serves little real purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of Meta are questions related to moderation, so the tag doesn’t really add any information

Comment: Follow-up: [Create \[community-standards\] tag in Super User Meta](https://meta.superuser.com/q/15000/1794161)